# Run whitesource/mend scan via CLI: error: 5001 - User is not allowed to perform this action

Tags: command-line-interface, whitesource

I have an access to the whitesource/mend server and I have installed & configured whithesource-CLI according to this [documentation](https://new.docs.whitesourcesoftware.com/en/whitesource-essentials-cli-quick-start-guide.html)

Install ws

Configure: ws configure

Enter API URL, api key, user key, etc

When I run `ws scan -u`, I'm receiving the following error:

```
ws scan -u
Initializing:

error: 5001 - User is not allowed to perform this action
```

I've tried to update default `product` value in `/path/to/.ws/config/settings.json` and also tried different key/value pairs like `product-key` and `product-token` but still seeing same error as above

However, when I use the same user key and run scan via jar `wss-unified-agent.jar` command the scan run looks good

```
java -jar /path/to/wss-unified-agent.jar -apiKey xxxxx -userKey xxxxx -productToken xxxxx -c /path/to/wss-unified-agent.config
```

Could someone advise or help me troubleshoot further ?

Answer (score -1):

Go to Mend server -> Login with your user -> Go to Home -> User Profile -> There you have one section for User Keys, generate user key there and use that user key while running the scan.

This should resolve your issue.